# The starting position of my custom draggable circular drag navbar is fixed on a certain point, beyond that it bugs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

I made a JSFiddle to help explain what's wrong:
https://jsfiddle.net/rickyjuh/s9cnm8w5/3/

I'm making a custom navigation bar for my website that uses JavaScript/JQuery to drag and rotate my logo to another "navigation bar item". It works when its on it's load position, but when you scroll down and try to drag it around, it bugs. The dragging area is locked on the load position of the logo and stays there no matter how far you scroll down.

I've tried to set an interval in which it constantly calculates the new position of the fixed "Gear" with my logo on it if you scroll down, but that didn't work and I can't find a solution anywhere.

I'm pretty sure the problem is either in calculating or in updating the position of the logo. Calculating the middle of the image happens in the following piece of code:

> ```
> var circle = document.getElementById('circle'), 
> picker = document.getElementById('picker'),
> pickerCircle = picker.firstElementChild,
> rect = circle.getBoundingClientRect(),
>
>
> center = { 
>           x: rect.left + rect.width / 2,   
>           y: rect.top + rect.height / 2
>           };
>
> rotate = function(x, y){
>   var deltaX = x - center.x,      deltaY = y - center.y,
> ```

I've discussed the matter above with various professors and searched online, but none could could resolve the bug. I was hoping someone on stackoverflow would know/resolve why my gear doesn't rotate the way it's supposed to after scrolling the page.

Comment: I think you're right about what the problem is. Perhaps on scroll you should just update the center variable and any other positioning variables? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp

Comment: I tried  window.onscroll = function() {center(); rotate()}; in order to refresh the center, but it still bugs out. Not sure I'm doing it right though

Comment: I think the rotate one is right there, but I think you'd need to re-set that center object not just say center();, something like window.onscroll = function() {center = {  x: rect.left + rect.width / 2,   y: rect.top + rect.height / 2 }; rotate()};

Comment: I fiddled with it for a bit, but no luck. Perhaps try swapping out event.pagex for screenx, (doesn't work in fiddle, but might work in full screen) since the gear is relative to the screen not really the page, you know?

Comment: It worked with another function that was "related" to screenX and Y. I fixed it by replacing those with clientX and clientY and it suddenly worked. Thanks you for your help, but I can't mark an comment as an answer I think

Comment: Awesome! No problemo, you answered it, not me! =]